# Angular Material Table, Update rows without all values

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I tried to update values one by one.But this update process affect all rows by same values in db.Could anyone help to me?

Here is my codes:

Angular:

```
export class UpdatedProductDialogComponent extends BaseComponent{

  
  constructor(private productService: ProductService,
    spiner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private alertify: AlertifyService,
    private dialogService: DialogService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private dialog: MatDialog) {
      super(spiner)

  }

 
  teams:{products:List_Product[],totalProductCount:number};
  listTeams:{id:string,name:string,about:string,position:string,region:string}[];

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {

    this.teams = await this.productService.read();
    
    this.listTeams = this.teams.products.map((r: any) => {
      return {

        name: r.name,
        id: r.id,
        position:r.position,
        about:r.about,
        region:r.region

      }
    });
  }



  update(object:any) {
    this.dialogService.openDialog( ({
      componentType:UpdateDialogComponent,
      data: UpdateState.Yes,
      afterClosed:async()=>{
        const id: string = object.target.attributes["id"].value;
        const name: string = object.target.value;
        const about:string=object.target.value;
        const position:string=object.target.value;
        const region:string=object.target.value;
        const datajitem: teamDataModel = new teamDataModel();
        datajitem.id = id;
        datajitem.name = name;
        datajitem.about=about;
        datajitem.position=position;
        datajitem.region=region;
        await this.productService.update(datajitem, () => {
          this.alertify.message("Team succesfully updated.", {
            dismissOthers: true,
            messageType: MessageType.Success,
            position: Position.TopRight
          })
        });

      }
    }))
  }


  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialog.closeAll();
  }

}
```

Html:

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update Roles</h5>
   
  </div>
  <div class="table-responsive" >



    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Team</th>
          
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="{{datajitem.id}}" *ngFor="let datajitem of listTeams;let i = index">
          <th scope="row">{{i + 1}}</th>
          <td>{{datajitem.id}}</td>
          <td>{{datajitem.name}}</td>
          <td>{{datajitem.about}}</td>
          <td>{{datajitem.position}}</td>
          <td>{{datajitem.region}}</td>

          <td>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="role-create">
              <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
              <input matInput [value]="datajitem.name" data-id="{{datajitem.id}}" (click)="update($event)">
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>

          <td>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="role-create">
              <mat-label>About</mat-label>
              <input matInput [value]="datajitem.about" data-id="{{datajitem.id}}"  (click)="update($event)">
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>

          <td>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="role-create">
              <mat-label>Position</mat-label>
              <input matInput [value]="datajitem.position" data-id="{{datajitem.id}}"  (click)="update($event)">
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>

          <td>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="role-create">
              <mat-label>Region</mat-label>
              <input matInput [value]="datajitem.region" data-id="{{datajitem.id}}"  (click)="update($event)">
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Backend :

Handle

```
 public class UpdateTeamCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<UpdateTeamCommandRequest, UpdateTeamCommandResponse>
 {
     readonly ILogger<UpdateTeamCommandHandler> _logger;
     readonly ITeamWriteRepository _teamWriteRepository;
     readonly ITeamReadRepository _teamReadRepository;
     public UpdateTeamCommandHandler(ITeamReadRepository teamReadRepository, ITeamWriteRepository teamWriteRepository, ILogger<UpdateTeamCommandHandler> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
         _teamReadRepository = teamReadRepository;
         _teamWriteRepository = teamWriteRepository;

     }

     public async Task<UpdateTeamCommandResponse> Handle(UpdateTeamCommandRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         Domain.Entities.Team product = await _teamReadRepository.GetByIdAsync(request.Id);
         product.Name = request.Name;
         product.About = request.About;
         product.Position = request.Position;
         product.Region= request.Region;
         await _teamWriteRepository.SaveAsync();
         _logger.LogInformation("Team Updated...");
         return new();
     }
 }


Controller:

[HttpPut("{Id}")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Admin")]
[AuthorizeDefinition(Menu = AuthorizeDefinitionConstants.Teams, ActionType = ActionType.Updating, Definition = "Update Team")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody,FromRoute] UpdateTeamCommandRequest updateProductCommandRequest)
{
    UpdateTeamCommandResponse response = await _mediator.Send(updateProductCommandRequest);
    return Ok();
}
```

I tried all values with a html button submit but its not working.Actually If i edited text and touched an Input element this do an event and just touched row must be updated.